# I need to convert this C++ struct into a C# struct for UDP binary sending

Tags: c#, c++, arrays, struct, initialization

I have this code provided by another author in C++ that I need to adapt to work in C#.  It's supposed to package up a struct and send it via udp.  I'm having a hard time getting the arrays to work and I'm wondering if I should be using some different method altogether?

```
#define SP_PACKET_SIZE 200
#define NAME_SIZE 64

struct spPacketStruct
{
    int Size;                               ///< Number of items in the data packet
    char Name[SP_PACKET_SIZE][NAME_SIZE];   ///< Data labels
    double Value[SP_PACKET_SIZE];           ///< Data packet values
};
```

I've converted the #define's into static declarations but I'm getting the error that I can't initialize the fields in structs.

Here's my converted struct:

```
    struct spPacketStruct
    {
        int Size;                                           /// Number of items in the data packet
        char[,] Name = new char[SP_PACKET_SIZE,NAME_SIZE];  /// Data labels
        double[] Value = new double[SP_PACKET_SIZE];                       /// Data packet values
    };
```

And the error:
spPacketStruct': cannot have instance property or field initializers in structs

Comment: `struct spPacketStruct
        {
            int Size;                                           /// Number of items in the data packet
            char[,] Name = new char[SP_PACKET_SIZE,NAME_SIZE];  /// Data labels
         double[] Value = new double[SP_PACKET_SIZE];                       /// Data packet values
        };`

Comment: spPacketStruct': cannot have instance property or field initializers in structs

Comment: You probably need to use the {} button in the editor.

Comment: I didn't push the save button, I pushed enter, expecting a line feed like a normal interface.  Can we discuss my problem and not stack overflow formatting?

Comment: One must be *very* careful when sending or receiving structs via sockets or whatever. Alignment on different machines can vary, byte order, ... Even on the same machine with same compiler but different compiler flags (well, doesn't apply for endianess, though), but yet worse if different languages are involved. I'd rather read the data into some byte array and pick what you need from there into your variables as needed.

Comment: @RobbieP. _"Can we discuss my problem and not stack overflow formatting? "_ Well, posting additional information in comments is pretty useless. So we have to discuss this before we can get on your _original problem_, since this needs to be properly specified in your question in 1st place.

Comment: @Aconcagua I agree...but this is a program I'm forced to communicate with due to the research environment I'm in...so is there a better way to create this kind of data packet?  It has to match that format to be read by the receivign program

Comment: Gotcha. That was confusing.  I edited my original question with the additional info

Comment: The structure is useless to you for comms, so don't waste your time trying to read into the `struct`. Fire up a packet analyzer like Wireshark and capture some traffic. You know what the data should look like, but you'll have  padding and endian problems you'll need to work out and Wireshark will tell you what the packets REALLY look like. Then you can do what @Aconcagua is talking about, write a deserializer that dumps the packet data into a structure you control and can use.